# How to put Powershell code into c# code using pipeline

Tags: c#, powershell

Here is what I use in Powershell:

```
get-vm -computername CN | select -ExpandProperty networkadapters | select macaddress, ipaddresses | Select-string -pattern "some mac"
```

Here is what i have in C# so far:

```
public static string GetIPFromMac(string mac, string Server) 
{
    Command command1 = new Command("get-vm");
    command1.Parameters.Add("ComputerName", Server);
    Command command = new Command("select");
    command.Parameters.Add("ExpandProperty", "networkadapter");
    Command command3 = new Command("select");
    command3.Parameters.Add("macaddress");
    command3.Parameters.Add("ipaddresses");
    Command command4 = new Command("select-string");
    command4.Parameters.Add("pattern", mac.Replace("-", ""));

    string ip = string.Empty;
    using(Pipeline hostPipeline = GetRunspace().CreatePipeline()) 
    {

        hostPipeline.Commands.Add(command1);
        hostPipeline.Commands.Add(command);
        hostPipeline.Commands.Add(command3);
        hostPipeline.Commands.Add(command4);
        ip = hostPipeline.Invoke()[0].ToString().Trim().Split(new []{' '})[1];
        hostPipeline.Stop();
    }
    return ip;
}
```

On this line I get the next error:

```
ip = hostPipeline.Invoke()[0].ToString().Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' })[1];
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException' occurred in
>   System.Management.Automation.dll

I think the problem is with the way I read the two "`Select`" Commands in, so my question is how would I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following lines:

```
Command command3 = new Command("select");
command3.Parameters.Add("macaddress");
command3.Parameters.Add("ipaddresses");
```

to

```
Command command3 = new Command("select");
command3.Parameters.Add("Property", new string[] { "macaddress", "ipaddresses" });
```